# How to get URL detail after redirection in angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on angular js application and using below method to get JSON data from the server. This works fine. I have to implement specific scenario, In case of session timeout I need to refresh the page.

The problem is that this application is legacy application and there is a filter which redirect the request to login page if the session is not alive. I am not allowed to change that filter for XMLHttpRequest.

Is there any way for angularJS to detect redirected url by filter.

```
makeCallPassingJsonObject: function (method, url, data, successCallback, failureCallBack) {

    return $http({
        method: method,
        url: url,
        async:true,
        data: data,
        responseType: 'json',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'
        }
    }).then(function(response){
       if(response.status ===200){
           successCallback(response.data, response.status, response);
       }else  if(response.status === 401){
           $state.go('gsd.shared.dashboard');
       }
       else{
           failureCallBack(response.data, response.status, response);
       }
    });
}
```

Below is the screenshot of browser debuging tool where url is visible. I am not sure how to access that url using angularJS. This url is different from window.location.pathParam

[image]

Comment: When you say "URL detail" you mean the querystring ? If is it so, check $location: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Comment: Its not the url in address bar.